# How do I solve the error in this query when using the CASE expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

first I get an error because the zero is an integer and it cannot be compared to a string, second, when I correct that using varchar I get an error on then

```
case when ECO.AlteratoRilasciamentoVentricolare = 0
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_AlteratoRilasciamentoVentricolare,
case when ECO.PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleReversibileVentricoloSinistro = 0 
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleReversibile,
case when ECO.PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleIrreversibileVentricoloSinistro = 0
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleIrreversibile,
case when ECO.PatternRestrittivoVentricoloSinistro = 0
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_PatternRestrittivo,
(SELECT cast(IDInterventovalore as varchar(5)) || '=' || valore  
FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi_valori val
```

Comment: Ok, I did format the code. Should be more readable like that

Comment: And what is the exact error you get?

Comment: This is the first error that I get: "character varying = integer doesn't exist"

Comment: I corrected that error, but then I get a syntax error on the use of then

Comment: show us your exact (new)  error message ..

Comment: Error SQL [42601]: ERROR: syntax error near or on "then"¶

Comment: @VegaOmega The code you posted looks fine, but (a) it's not the full code so we might be missing something important, and (b) you said you corrected it and now get an error around "then", but you haven't posted that updated code so we can't see what new issue might be causing that error.

Comment: You can't put a `CASE`  before the `SELECT` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
case when ECO.AlteratoRilasciamentoVentricolare = 0::varchar
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_AlteratoRilasciamentoVentricolare,
case when ECO.PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleReversibileVentricoloSinistro = 0::varchar
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleReversibile,
case when ECO.PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleIrreversibileVentricoloSinistro = 0::varchar
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_PatternMitralicoPseudonormaleIrreversibile,
case when ECO.PatternRestrittivoVentricoloSinistro = 0::varchar
          then '0=No'
     else '1=Si' end as VentricoloSinistro_PatternRestrittivo,
(SELECT cast(IDInterventovalore as varchar(5)) || '=' || valore  
FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi_valori val
```

Cast your numbers to varchar as above, or simply put tics around them 
example: "case when fubar='0'".

one of your tables likely has a varchar column instead of a number. I'd recommend setting your tables to numeric if you have the option to update the table structure.